# Why didn't Picard have his baldness cured?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, jean-luc-picard

Why wouldn't Picard have his male pattern baldness cured?  Surely they can do this in the 24th Century.

Maybe people are way less vain in the 24th Century, but I think I remember Picard showing Beverly a picture of his younger self in Nemesis, and he was very bald in it.  So it seems he was afflicted by unusually early pattern baldness.

So why wouldn't he have had that corrected?

Comment: **Reporter:** *Surely they would have cured baldness by the 24th century."* **Gene Roddenberry:** *"In the 24th century, they wouldn't care"*. The implication is that a cure for baldness is not a high priority item.

Comment: IT’S NOT A DISEASE